# How to set a select list value from a selection of selects in JQuery

Tags: jquery

For each select list in my form, I want to set the selected option to the value in `record[]` that matches the id of the select. i.e. the field name, which is what I've labelled the select with.

This code doesnt work, it's setting something else *(my select list doesnt switch to my value from `record[]`, though `record[this.id]` is what I am expecting, and of course when I invert the below to build up a record to post, all I get is what I had to start with, not the new value I selected from the dropdown)*.

I thought I could just use `.val()` to set a select list value instead to churning through all the options.

```
$('#dialog-edit-'+tableName+'-form select').each(function() {
    $('#'+this.id).val(record[this.id]);                
});
```

Comment: Is the select tags id indexed as it is in `record[]` ?

Comment: should be just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dxj3v/1/

Comment: OK, I'll look closer still, cos it aint working but you guys think it should. and yes, <select id="fieldname"> and record['fieldname']

Comment: hang on folks, I think I've been ajaxed here. Maxim's was working and now it's not. I will get to the bottom of this and then we can clean this up.

Comment: yes, there's nothing wrong with my original code,  $('#'+this.id).val(record[this.id]); works just dandy. But my populator hadnt finished running. I set it to async : false for now till I get my head around deferred objects. Not sure what to do with this question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you should try this: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/Emnt6

**HTML**

```
     <select id="test1">
    <option value="test1-1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test1-2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test1-3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select id="test2">
    <option value="test2-1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2-2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test2-3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select id="test3">
    <option value="test3-1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test3-2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test3-3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var record = { test1: 'test1-1', test2: 'test2-3', test3: 'test3-2' };

    $('select').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).find('option[selected]').removeAttr('selected');
        $(this).find('option[value='+record[id]+']').prop('selected', true);                
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks maxim, I had to close the string on appending ],  element.find('option[value='+record[id]+']').attr('selected', 'selected'); but it still doesnt seem to work

Comment: I have updated the code to the test one. It will show the correct way to do this.